# Android Maven Unexpected Top-Level Exception

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea

I'm getting the error which I shared below. It's related to maven (imho) and I know there is something wrong with my pom.xml but nothing found. I searched for all the same topics and the latest point what I reached is something should be excluded from some artifact because that something tries to add itself multiple times as error says. Btw it can be compiled without any problem through maven however I get this error when I want to run "package" on it.

[INFO] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/codehaus/classwor
lds/BytesURLConnection;
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:12
2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.a</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <android.plugin.version>3.6.0</android.plugin.version>
        <platform.version>2.3.3</platform.version>
        <sdk_path>D:\Android</sdk_path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
            <version>4.47</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>10</platform>
                        <path>${sdk_path}</path>
                    </sdk>
                    <dexOptimize>false</dexOptimize>
                    <dex>
                        <preDex>false</preDex>
                        <preDexLibLocation>/tmp/predexedLibs</preDexLibLocation>
                    </dex>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove below part

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
       <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. and insert below lines under build element

   ```
   <build>
       <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
       <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
   ```

the latest and correct pom.xml should be seen as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.holyscreen</groupId>
    <artifactId>HolyScreenApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <android.plugin.version>3.6.0</android.plugin.version>
        <platform.version>2.3.3</platform.version>
        <sdk_path>D:\Android</sdk_path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
            <version>4.47</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>10</platform>
                        <path>${sdk_path}</path>
                    </sdk>
                    <dexOptimize>false</dexOptimize>
                    <dex>
                        <preDex>false</preDex>
                        <preDexLibLocation>/tmp/predexedLibs</preDexLibLocation>
                    </dex>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark image. According to Stack Overflow guidelines, marking an answer as 'accepted' is the correct approach.

Comment: I did it already but it said "you can accept your own answer tomorrow"

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for sending you a false alarm in that case :)